Pure CSS dynamic HTML table layout issue
I want to display two HTML tables (a main list and a detail view) in a responsive manner, such that at Boostrap's xl breakpoint the two are shown side by side, and otherwise one below the other (with e.g. a 30/70 split).
Both tables can be quite long, and so I have them set up for tbody scrolling like this so that they stay within the screen viewport:
tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 80vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

table thead, table tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

The two tables are generated by Angular components, and both are contained inside a Bootstrap row:
<div class="row">
    <app-list class="col-xl-4" />
    <app-detail class="col-xl-8" />
</div>

This layout is working fine for the side-by-side mode.  I cannot for the life of me find a way to shrink the (max) heights in top-to-bottom mode.
As a general design principle I want the two components to be standalone and independent of any media or container queries because they may get re-used in other layouts.
I hoped to be able to use media queries from the containing app level component's CSS to control the sizes of the two components' host elements.  I've tried numerous combinations of supplying max-height values via vh and vb at every level of the DOM tree but nothing is working.
A further consideration is that if the app-list view only contains a few items I'd like the app-detail view to use all remaining available space (i.e. the ratio could be 10/90, but cannot exceed 30/70).
Is this even possible with pure CSS, or do I need to catch resize events.
NB:  I'm developing for latest Chrome - backwards compatibility is not a concern.

Could you share a simple snippet with minimal code on stackblitz, so that the issue is reproducible and expected output from the stackblitz you need. thanks!

@NarenMurali https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jzb5uq?file=index.html

@NarenMurali the particular issue I've experienced is demonstrated here - although the visible part of the tables appear to get constrained, the top table actually ends up hidden behind the bottom table and only some of the 40 rows are reachable.

have you tried  @container query?

@MatanSanbira I think that would be getting the logic backwards?  I want the tables (with their scrolling bodies) to automatically completely fill their containers and have no explicit knowledge of their geometries.    Nor do I want the containers to have to deep dive into the components' DOM trees (to e.g. explicitly set the height of the tbody elements) because that would be poor component isolation.  I think this should be possible using relative vb units but I can't make it work.

@Alnitak The table does not care about the container, you must implement a JS solution to dynamically adapt the height

ignoring the dual table issue, this stackblitz demonstrates how the tbody's max-height (expressed in vb units) is apparently ignoring any viewport size applied to its ancestor containing blocks.  It seems to be treating vb equivalent to vh, and this feels wrong.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mhmss7?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Maybe I'm just fundamentally misunderstanding vb units.  My reading is that 50vb means half of height of the containing block, but it's just not working for me, even without tables involved.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-c4cpqu?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Hmm, it seems the keyword I was missing is initial containing block.

@MatanSanbira it turns out that container units (without explicit @container queries) have actually helped a lot.   By specifying container: CSS properties for the enclosing elements I've been able to replace the vb units in my tbody heights with cqb units and now my tables fit within their containing elements perfectly happy.   I didn't yet solve the issue of how to shrink the main list to allow more room for the detail view when the main list is short, but good progress has been made, thanks!

(requiring container: properties on the elements created in the main component's CSS is for me adequate isolation between the components)
